# Center single column in ListView holding an image

Tags: wpf, listview, alignment

I have a Listview that has three columns. The last columns holds an image that only gets displayed if the data the column bind to is true.

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="lstPrinters"  ItemsSource="{Binding PrinterCollection}">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="250" Header="UNC" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UNC}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Default"  >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <Image Width="16" Height="16"  Source="/PrinterController.Agent;component/images/GreenTick.png">
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" >
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDefault}" Value="false">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDefault}" Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Image.Style>
                            </Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

I want the image to be horizontially centred in the column but no matter how I try it wont center.  I have tried so many ways to do this to be honest I am starting to forget what I have and haven't tried! I have followed all the SO articles I can find that relate to this issue but none have worked.  I only want this one column to be centred.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your ListView:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: If I am honest I don't understand why this has only centered the one column but it works a dream!  Thank you.

Comment: @Fred This just allows the column to have all of the cell to work with, meaning if you set them to be centered, they actually can be.

Comment: Ok that makes sense now. I have not worked with WPF for long.  Didn't like it to begin with but starting to change my mind.  I guess its all about not liking what you don't understand.  Thanks again.